# Unity dummy resolve to minimize the cost of object initialization

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, prism

I have a component that the constuctor takes a long time to execute (it uses SAPBOBSdll to connect to a SAP Business One database) in my Prism aplication. I register it in the Unity container:

```
_container.RegisterType<IConnection, Connection>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

When I try to resolve this component it takes a long time (arround 15 seconds). Is it bad practice to pre resolve the component using a different thread so it doesn't block my program when I try to use it? I do this just after the register line and it works well, but I have a weird feeling about it.

```
new Task(()=> _container.Resolve<IConnection>()).Start();
```

Is it OK to do this or should I do it another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggested solution sounds good to me, especially if you put that code under the Module's Initialize() method, and make sure that the module is loaded when available (as opposed to on demand).

Maybe in order to make what you're doing more explicit to other readers of the code, I would write something along the lines of:

```
new Task(()=> _container.RegisterInstance<IConnection>(_container.Resolve<Connnection>())).Start();
```

This makes it clear to the reader that you are resolving explicitly in order to register that instance as a singleton for future resolves of that type.